# Is "I will do X and respond" preferable to "I will do X and revert"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

In the emails I keep seeing someone responding with
"I will do X and revert"

asked them what do they mean by that, they said it means respond back.
It doesn't seem right to me, I have been looking for usages of revert, all I see that makes sense is to
return to previous state ( which doesn't mean anything to me ).

Is it preferable to use "I will do X and respond (back)" to "I will do X and revert"?

Comment: I have no idea what *revert* means in this context. Certainly, *respond* and *revert* mean different things.

Comment: @ThePhoton : Yes , that is exactly that, thank you, it was not suggested by the site nor it came up for me in google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Indian English. Just like American English and British English have different rules, so does Indian English. If you are Indian and communicating with Americans or Brits, you will make yourself more clear if you say "respond" instead of "revert". If you are speaking to Indians, "revert" will probably be perfectly clear (but I'm not an expert on Indian English).